# Grouped Product with Fixed Sub-item Quantities

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm working on a Magento site that has a number of simple products.  There's also a "holiday package" which combines several simple products into one, at a discounted price:

- 6 of Item A
- 2 of Item B
- 2 of Item C
- 2 of Item D

The "**grouped**" product type is pretty close to what I need - it allows each item to keep track of it's own stock, and when it comes time to ship and estimate packages, it tries to pack the containers using the weight/volume of each individual item.  (**This shipping aspect is very important**, as we need to pack the boxes as efficiently as possible - using a simple product with an estimated size for all items may not work).

However, we do **not** want the customer to be able to choose the quantity of each item.  The customer should instead be asked to choose how many holiday packages they would like.

Is a grouped product the best approach?  Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Magento 1.5.1, the best solution should be the bundle product. There, you can define a price, a quantity for each item in the backend. You can block the user to change the quantity for these items, not for the bundle product (you could too if you want but it's not your need here).

We do like that for some of our product. Check the screenshot to see an example of configuration

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help and the screenshot!  This will definitely fit my needs, just need to make a few tweaks to the template to hide the the individual item listing (since nobody will ever need to see that).

Comment: @Colin: yes, completely agree, I need too to customize the display in frontend